# Convert Roman Numerals into Word-Form When the String is Multiple Words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created the below function to convert roman numerals into word-form. It works as intended. If the building/string ends in a roman numeral from I-X, it converts it to the word. There is one hole that I know of (if the roman numeral is not the last word). I can't think of how to implement that. Thoughts?

Also, I'm pretty new to Python so I am curious if there was anyway to clean up the code. It looks bulky to me.

```
def replace_roman_numerals(string):
if len(string.split()) > 1:     # if the community name has more than one word, split the words, else return community as is
    first, *middle, last = string.split()
else:
    first = ""
    middle = ""
    last = ""
w = string.split()  # splits the community name into words
lw = w[len(w)-1]    # returns the last word in the community
# convert RN into a word if the last word in the community is a RN and remove excessive blanks and characters from the middle variable
if lw in ("I", "1"):         return " ".join((first + " " + str(middle)[1:-1].replace("'","").replace(",","") + " One").split())
elif lw in ("II", "2"):      return " ".join((first + " " + str(middle)[1:-1].replace("'","").replace(",","") + " Two").split())
elif lw in ("III", "3"):     return " ".join((first + " " + str(middle)[1:-1].replace("'","").replace(",","") + " Three").split())
elif lw in ("IV", "4"):      return " ".join((first + " " + str(middle)[1:-1].replace("'","").replace(",","") + " Four").split())
elif lw in ("V", "5"):       return " ".join((first + " " + str(middle)[1:-1].replace("'","").replace(",","") + " Five").split())
elif lw in ("VI", "6"):      return " ".join((first + " " + str(middle)[1:-1].replace("'","").replace(",","") + " Six").split())
elif lw in ("VII", "7"):     return " ".join((first + " " + str(middle)[1:-1].replace("'","").replace(",","") + " Seven").split())
elif lw in ("VIII", "8"):    return " ".join((first + " " + str(middle)[1:-1].replace("'","").replace(",","") + " Eight").split())
elif lw in ("IX", "9"):      return " ".join((first + " " + str(middle)[1:-1].replace("'","").replace(",","") + " Nine").split())
elif lw in ("X", "10"):       return " ".join((first + " " + str(middle)[1:-1].replace("'","").replace(",","") + " Ten").split())
else:                 return " ".join((first + " " + str(middle)[1:-1].replace("'","").replace(",","") + " " + lw).split())
```

Inputs:

```
s = "Park III"
s = replace_roman_numerals(s)
print (s)
s = "American Tower - Bldg IV"
print (replace_roman_numerals(s))
s = "Estancia"
print (replace_roman_numerals(s))
s = "Park Place 9"
print (replace_roman_numerals(s))
```

Outputs are:

```
Park Three
American Tower - Bldg Four
Estancia
Park Place Nine
```

Comment: Could you give an example of any inputs and outputs?

Comment: They're at the bottom of the code with the s variable - "Park III, American Tower - Bldg 4, Estancia, Park Place Nine". I haven't come across anything that has the roman numeral in the middle of the string but it's only a matter of time. Something like - "Oaks III at The Twins" should be "Oaks Three at The Twins".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a bit more python-ish approach:

```py
conv_map={"1": "One", "I": "One", "2": "Two", "II": "Two", "3": "Three", "III": "Three", "4": "Four", "IV": "Four", "5": "Five", "V": "Five", "6": "Six", "VI": "Six", "7": "Seven", "VII": "Seven", "8": "Eight", "VIII": "Eight", "9": "Nine", "IX": "Nine", "10": "Ten", "X": "Ten"}

def replace_roman_numerals(inputStr, map_=conv_map):
    w = inputStr.split()
    w[-1]=map_.get(w[-1], w[-1])
    return ' '.join(w)

s = "Park III"
s = replace_roman_numerals(s)
print (s)
s = "American Tower - Bldg IV"
print (replace_roman_numerals(s))
s = "Estancia"
print (replace_roman_numerals(s))
s = "Park Place 9"
# in case you'd need it - you can also pass other conversion map:
print (replace_roman_numerals(s, conv_map))
```

Outputs:

```py
Park Three
American Tower - Bldg Four
Estancia
Park Place Nine
```

Comment: Thanks! This is much more condense than mine. I tried to use a dictionary when I first approached it, but my code kept replacing all "II" with OneOne. Do you have any thoughts for when the roman numeral/number shows up mid string like "TW III Apartments"? It would be "TW Three Apartments".

Comment: Hm, theoretically if you replace this: ```w[-1]=map_.get(w[-1], w[-1])``` with that: ```w=map(lambda x: map_.get(x, x), w)``` you will do the analogical replacement for all words. For just the middle one - you can just add ```if(len(w)>2): w[1]=map_.get(w[1], w[1])``` for middle= second word, or:  ```if(len(w)>2): w[-2]=map_.get(w[-2], w[-2])``` for middle= one to last.

Comment: Dude - this is great! I appreciate your help. The analogical replacement is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm working on cleaning data sets from some external sources (typically a vendor) and run a comparison with our internal naming convention to find the closest match.